# how to initialize weights with the neuralnet package?

Tags: r

I am using the neuralnet package in R, but I have a problem when I want to initialize certain number of initial weights for my network. I have tried to do it based on the results that I got from the default random weights generated, but no luck at all.

This is the part where I should put the initial weights:

```
weigths<-c(-0.3,0.2,
    0.2,0.05,
    0,2,-0.1,
    -0.1,0.2,0.2)
net=neuralnet(to~x1+x2,tdata,hidden=2,threshold=0.01,constant.weights=weights)
```

because I am considering that the weights follow this pattern:

```
Intercept.to.1layhid1  -5.0556934519949
x1.to.1layhid1         10.9208362719511
x2.to.1layhid1         12.9996270590530
Intercept.to.1layhid2   3.7047601228351
x1.to.1layhid2         -2.5636252939619
x2.to.1layhid2         -2.5759077405754
Intercept.to.to        -1.6494794336705
1layhid.1.to.to         1.3502874764968
1layhid.2.to.to         1.6969811621181
```

but when I apply it I got the error:

```
Error in constant.weights != 0
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `startweights` argument to initialize custom weights.  This is in the documentation:

```
help(neuralnet)

startweights:
  a vector containing starting values for the weights. 
  The weights will not be randomly initialized.
```

The `constant.weights` is used to specify fixed weights those which you would have excluded with the `exclude` agrument.