# Build a neural network with known weights and bias

Tags: r, neural-network

I have a known configuration nodes, weights, bias values, and activation function (tanh) for a neural network.  I'd like to build that neural network as some 'neural network' object in R by proscribing the parts, and not fitting a network.  How can I do this?  I see many options to fit a neural network, but cannot find out how to build a network when I already know the components.

Comment: This question may lack some details. It sounds like a basic read-the-docs about internals or reverse-engineer internals problem (to know how to put those values into the memory or input-file if readNN is supported). And if the network comes from some other library like tensorflow, theano and co. additional problems may arise (e.g. different internal calculations; e.g. evaluation of complicated gradients)

Comment: This is completely dependent on which neural network package you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R do provide `startweights` argument to initialize custom weights, see [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880539/how-to-initialize-weights-with-the-neuralnet-package). I also won't see citations for changing bias and transfer function.

Either use MATLAB (*which is not a good idea for a R expert*) or better design custom network based on following fact:

ANN is just a set of maths operations on input vectors and output vectors, where math operations are adjustment of weights based on error term in a loop using simple back-propogation. **Use vectors and maths operations ONLY in R to design a simple ANN with back-propogation training**

Comment: Thank you, this helps.  What I really wanted to do was to build some simple toy examples for demonstration purposes with weights that I was able to set rather than get from training.  I've taken to training a 'nnet' model on some random data just to get an object of the appropriate node structure, then poking in the appropriate 'wts' list entry of the 'nnet' object.  I was hoping to leverage any good existing package to do this easily, but as you said, I may just write the nodes, wts and biases, and activation function connections myself.